# WithEvents vs AddHandler in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, events, addhandler

I asking myself what the differences are between

```vb
Dim WithEvents EClass As New EventClass
```

and

```vb
AddHandler Obj.XEvent, AddressOf Me.XEventHandler
```

In which context you should use the first or the second?

Can anyone explain it? Thanks.

Comment: The first is just declaring an object var which is capable of raising events.  The second actually attaches an event handler for an event. If you are doing the first because it is not a UI object, then you also need the second.  There is no "versus"

Comment: ...actually, in VB the first statement will allow the IDE to expose all the EventClass events in the 2 editor dropdowns.  The second allows you to hook up the event to a method which you typed in rather than had the IDE create from the Object-Event dropdowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WithEvents supports the `Handles` keyword.  Which you can apply to a method.  When the VB.NET compiler encounters it, it will generate code in the constructor of the class that automagically calls AddHandler.  So you don't have to write it yourself.

It is pretty convenient to designers, both the WPF and the Winforms designers rely on it for example.  It eliminates the likelihood that you get a build error when you delete an event handler, you can't forget to also delete the AddHandler statement.  And it is very compatible with code written in previous versions of Visual Basic, like VB6.  Which makes it easier to convert old projects.  Probably the major reason WithEvents was implemented in .NET, C# does not have anything similar.

There's also a good reason to really dislike it.  There's a nasty problem with it that to this day still has not been solved.  In order to support Edit and Continue, the compiler creates WeakReferences in the Debug build.  The debugger ensures that those WeakReference objects are cleaned up again.  That does not happen when you run without a debugger.  That's a leak that will eventually crash your program, albeit that it takes a while.  This makes it *very* important that you only ever deploy the Release build of a VB.NET program.